# configure jmeter setting based on request per secon

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

i am new to Load testing and would like configure my jmeter  setting for the following requirement below. My understanding is Theard are different from request per second. If so what will be values in thread group for the below requirement.

"Initial load 20 request/second, increase load with 100 request/second for each minute.
Perform load test until we see an increase in latency "

Comment: You have not provided enough information to answer this question. Please find and read some basic tutorials on load testing.

Answer (score 1):

You should put something very high into Thread Group and use one of the following approaches to define your load pattern:

- [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) - it comes bundled with JMeter
- [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) or [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/)- available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project

In order to automatically stop the test when latency exceeds threshold you can use [AutoStop Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/AutoStop/), again it comes with JMeter Plugins.

In general latency is networking related metric so even if your application is slow as a snail you can have low or even zero latency so I would recommend considering response time and/or transactions per second metrics as well.